# Vandermonde-like determinant

Tags: determinant

I want to prove that
$$\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix}
    a_1 & a_2 & ... a_{N+1} \\
    1 & 1 & ... 1 \\
    a^{-1}_1 & a^{-1}_2 & ... a^{-1}_{N+1} \\
    ... & ... & ...  \\
    a^{-N+1}_1 & a^{-N+1}_2 & ... a^{-N+1}_{N+1} \\
    \end{vmatrix} 
&= \frac{\prod_{j=2}^{N+1}(a_1-a_j)}{a^{N-1}_1}
\begin{vmatrix}
    1 & ...& 1 \\
    a^{-1}_2 & ...& a^{-1}_{N+1} \\
    ... & ... & ...  \\
    a^{-N+1}_2 & ... &a^{-N+1}_{N+1} \\
    \end{vmatrix} \\[2mm]
&\\
&
& 
\end{align}$$
I check that this relation holds for $N\in\{1,2\}$.Please help me find general proof.

Comment: If you multiply column $k$ of the left matrix by $a_k^{N-1}$, don't you get a vandermonde determinant? Similarly for the right matrix?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you are right. This is indeed a Vandermonde determinant.

Comment: I nearly see that if I multiply both sides by the product of the coefficients I obtain the Vandermonde determinant of size $N+1$ on the left hand side and of size $N$ on the right hand side?

Comment: Yeah, more or less.

Comment: For this problem: normalize both matrices to Vandermonde and go to Wikipedia; keeping care to put the normalization back in:)   Are you interested in the paper; that really twists the mind further in (as I recall) :)  If so, I will try to unearth it from years of papers (composting digital math papers here).

Comment: @rrogers it will be great :)

Comment: Here is what I found on my computer.  Doesn't match what I remember, but don't be put of by the title the internal matter, page 5-... , deals directly and indirectly with VanderMonde matrices.  https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9902004.pdf   The author has another later paper that deals with combinatorial matrices (i.e. pascal).  Something I used extensively.  Another fairly elementary reference: https://web.deu.edu.tr/halil.oruc/vandermondefactorization.pdf   and a historical paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.4716.pdf  Of course google scholar has many available varients.